# Is there a way to download usage statistics for emails sent using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is there a way to download usage statistics for emails sent using AWS SES.
I want to download in excel format (preferably) meta data about all emails sent- send-to email, subject, date and time of sending.

Is that possible? or is that information available over API?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html

Comment: @favoretti this only provided stats about accepts, rejects, etc.. but no details about the subject of the email sent, who was the email sent to, etc.... Is that possible at all?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of. You can only do what’s on that page. Haven’t found anything else yet either.